# Category archives with monthly pagination

Tags: categories, pagination, archives

How would I go about doing the following:

I need to setup a prev/next type pagination where posts within a category archive are split into months.

For example, if I navigate to the News category, I should get all posts in the News category for this month only. I could then hit the prev link to get all of the posts for last month in the News category.

This can replace the default settings where posts are simply paginated by a specific number of posts per page.

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: did you try the automatic archives (/date/yyyy/mm), and setting the query on this template to get all posts `numberposts = -1`, and placing manual links to the next/previous month?

Comment: Yes but that displays all posts in every category for the given month. I need a way to only show a specific category.

Comment: Okay, so you would have to add the category=$categoryID to your query, $categoryID being the ID of your news category.